# Como crear un ciclo de widgets en PySide6

Tags: python, pyside

estoy creando un proyecto en pyside sobre punto de venta y quiero crear grupo de widgets en donde puedan estar vinculados con las compras que realice el cliente la interfaz gráfica crea de manera que el vendedor cada vez que introduzca un producto nuevo al inventario se cree un grupo de widgets label con los detalles del producto una imagen y un QPushButton, pero no tengo ni idea de como empezarlo alguien me puede ayudar???.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega lo que has intentado o investigado para poderte brindar información útil. Saludos

Comment: Adhiero al comentario anterior. Asimismo, te recomiendo crearte tu propia clase con el grupo de widgets que necesites. El uso de listas para PySide no tiene mucha versatilidad como para la tarea que quieres realizar.

Answer (score 0):

```
def CrearProduc(self):
    contadorY=0
    contadorX=0
    self.ListaDeWidgets=[None,]
    for i in range(1,13):#rango de productos que pueden entrar
        self.ListaDeWidgets.insert(i,QWidget(self.PrinWin.pageCliente))
        self.ListaDeWidgets[i].setGeometry(QRect((315*contadorX)+40,contadorY+25,300,200))
        if (i % 4)==0:
            contadorY += 215
            contadorX = 0
        else:
            contadorX += 1
            pass
        print(contadorY)
        self.ListaDeWidgets[i].setStyleSheet(u"background-color:rgb(0,0,0);")
    pass
    print(self.ListaDeWidgets)
```

Este es mi ejemplo de como solucione mi problema si algo de mi codigo puedo mejorar por favor háganme lo saber.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mejor edita la pregunta para incluir está información.